# Sitecore- Dynamically adding link in rich text editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I have a shared text displaying the content from its RichText field and I want a link in that RichText so that on click of that link a page(.ascx) should get displayed. The page that will get displayed is not present in sitecore content tree. It just a sublayout in code behind.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: ASCX is user control. When we add it into our page say 'Default.aspx' it becomes the part of that page but not whole page. So you can not use .ASCX as standalone. If you want to see it,you have to place it into some page and then only you can view it from browser.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a sub-layout and point to that ascx file. And then create a page provide the proper presentation details with layout and sub-layouts and then provide the link for that page in Rich Text.